# How to generate the Microsoft code analysis xml file in a Visual C++ project?

Tags: c++, static-analysis, microsoft-code-analysis

I have created c++ project from visual studio 2019 and ran below syntax from command prompt. But log file was not generated. How to generate the Microsoft code analysis xml file in a Visual C++ project?

`msbuild /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release project.sln /p:RunCodeAnalysis=true /p:CodeAnalysisLogFile=output.xml`